# How to test MatDialogRef overlayref

Tags: angular, ts-jest

How to test dialogref from MatDialogRef?

```
dialogRef: MatDialogRef<testComponent>;

    showBackdrop() {
     const backdrop = this.dialogRef['_ref'].overlayRef._backdropElement.style.display = 'block'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const matDialogRefMock = {
        _ref : {
            overlayRef: {
                _backdropElement: {
                    style: {
                        display: 'block'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    };
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Assuming, that is, that you intended this as an answer—which, absent any further context, I gather to be the case. If not, that's also likely part of why nobody else has answered this question, as it looks like you've already solved your issue.